# For Loop only two things included C++

Tags: c++, loops

Lets say I have

```
int j = 23;
for (j < 20; j++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I know it seems stupid in this context but is this possible? Or do you have to do

```
int j = 23;
for (j; j < 20; j++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: what about `do { } while (++j < 20);`? Different semantics of course.

Comment: you will never do any stuff as 23 > 20

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd typically use an empty initializer:

```
for (; j < 20; ++j)
```

Granted, it's just an example, but if `j` is initialized `23`, the `for` loop will never execute at all.

Answer (score 6):

You always have three components, but any of them may be blank.  So your first example could be written:

```
int j = 23;
for (; j < 20; j++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

(Of course, this doesn't do anything at all, because the initial value of `j` is bigger than 23, so the loop immediately terminates).

Answer (score 5):

You can do only two things, but you need two semicolons, since a for loop consists of an initializer, a condition, and an operation to perform on every loop. You can of course leave any one of these blank

```
for (; j < 20; j++) { 
     // do stuff
}
```

You could even have an infinite loop that still incremented j, for example

```
for (int j = 0; ; j++) { 
     // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't omit the semicolon there.  It should be:

```
int j = 23;
for (; j < 20; j++) {
  //do stuff
}
```